# Probability Question : PMF

Tags: probability

[image]

So this is a problem I'm stuck on. I managed to solve the first (a) problem, but I don't know how to solve the second or the third one.

All the random variables $X_1$ to $X_n$ are independent. So E[X] would be $\frac{17}{16}$ and E[Y] would be $(\frac{17}{16})^n$. But  I can't figure out the next problems.

Comment: Note that we can define the value of $Y_n$ in terms of the number of $X_i$s which are 2. Given that there are $k$ $X_i$s taking the value 2, we know that $Y_n = \frac{2^k}{8^{n-k}} = 2^k 2^{3(k-n)} = 2^{4k-3n}$. Does this get you started?

Answer (score 0):

For item (b), note that for Y $\geq$ 1, the ratio of the number of 2's to 1/8ths must be $\geq$ 3:1. Therefore, for N terms, $P(Y_{N} \geq 1) = 1 - P(Y_{N} < 1) = 1 - \sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor \frac{3(N-.5)}{4}\rfloor} Binomial(p=0.5,i,N)$, where we are modeling the process as coin tosses with heads = 2, tails = 1/8. Think about something along these lines and I think you'll make progress.